# mapping multiple collection with one entity

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, mapping

I have a four entity class as listed bellow.
the mapping requirement is like-
1-Customer may have multiple address
2-Customer may have multiple and unique contact numbers.
3-Customer may have multiple and unique email-id's.
while running the application, i am getting the MultipleBagFetchException becoz of multi collection or might be bcoz of wrong mapping., can any one help me...
thanks

first

```
public class Customer{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)", name = DatabaseConstants.ID)
private UUID id;

private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;

private Date dob;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Gender gender;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "customer")
@JoinColumn(name="department_id")
@Embedded
private List<Address> address;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "customer")
@Embedded
private Set<Email> email;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "customer")
@Embedded
private Set<Mobile> mobile;
}
```

Second-

```
public class Address {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)", name = DatabaseConstants.ID)
private UUID id;
private String country;
private String state;
private String city;
private String streetAddress;
private String zip;
private String addressType;
@ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
private Customer customer;
}
```

Third-

```
public class Email {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)", name = DatabaseConstants.ID)
private UUID id;
@javax.validation.constraints.Email
private String emailId;
@ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
private Customer customer;
private boolean primary;
}
```

Fourth-

```
public class Mobile {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)", name = DatabaseConstants.ID)
private UUID id;

private String mobileNumber;
private boolean primary;
@ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
private Customer customer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need @Embedded attribute on these

```
private List<Address> address;
private Set<Email> email;
private Set<Mobile> mobile;
```

@Embedded is required only when you want to embed a composite value. Here you have a simple one to many relationship between entities. Remove the @Embedded on the class members and @Embeddable on child classes if they are present and put @Entity if not already present.